# Reactjs set state for each item in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a array of objects called `data` in fact it take from API in real code, I can not change its structure. so I want to display data in a table, it has a nested objects called `list` which contains location and price, I want to display as select option when user change location display own price front of it.

```
{data.serverTypes.map((Item, Index) => {
return (
  <tr key={Index}>
    <td>{Item.id}</td>
    <td>
      <select onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}>
        {Item.list.map((Location, Idx) => {
          return (
            <option value={Location.price}>
              {Location.location}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>{price}</td>
  </tr>
);
})}
```

But I can not figure out how can I display each price form each location when I iterate object because I define state outside of loop. for better understanding please see live demo, change select option to see result. already it display price for all, but I want to display each location's price front of it.

**[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-haze-ve0r7f?file=/src/App.js)**

Comment: You'll need to create a component for an item. I'm sure if it is what you actually want : https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-frog-gzw21i?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a child component for each `ServerType` to hold its own state.

Also, you are selecting a location, not selecting a price. So price can be derived from `selectedLocation`.

```
export default function App() {
  const data = {
    serverTypes: [
      {
        id: 1,
        list: [
          { location: "usa", price: 1000 },
          { location: "germany", price: 2000 }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        list: [
          { location: "usa", price: 2500 },
          { location: "germany", price: 3000 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>location</th>
            <th>price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <thead>
          {data.serverTypes.map((serverType, index) => (
            <ServerType key={index} serverType={serverType} />
          ))}
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

const ServerType = ({ serverType }) => {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState(0);
  const { id, list } = serverType;
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{id}</td>
      <td>
        <select onChange={({ target }) => setSelectedLocation(target.value)}>
          {list.map(({ location }, index) => {
            return <option value={index}>{location}</option>;
          })}
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>{list[selectedLocation].price}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit eager-jones-v3kih3]